# Deleting a parent object if no child is created to match it's ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Is there an easy way to retroactively delete a parent object if no child is created?

has_many and belongs_to relationship.

I want to keep my parent.id and child.parent_id synchronized, and if my parent object persist, and a child is not created, I am left with asynchronous ID"s.

Any help?

I am keeping this general and looking for general answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by keeping the ids 'synchronized'. If you are using the parent to create the child like so: `parent.children.create(attributes)`, they should never be different.

It sounds, though, like what you are doing is creating the parent first and then the child but all in the same action. Sometimes the child isn't being created because of failed validations or something, however, and you don't want the parent to be created either. There are several ways to do this.

The cleanest is with `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Models:

```
class Parent
  has_many :children, inverse_of: parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of :children
end
```

Controller

```
ParentController
  def create
    parent.create(parent_params)
  end

  def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:parent_attribute_1, :parent_attribute_2, :children_attributes => [:child_attribute_1, etc.])
  end
end
```

Your params would have to be nested like the above structure, but it allows the parent to accept attributes for the child and instantiate and create both at the same time.

Alternatively, you could use create both the parent and the child inside a transaction block which would roll back all transactions done if an exception is thrown. So you could use `save!` and `create!` methods to ensure that the transaction would only get completed if everything inside the transaction block worked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help!  I will check this out. 

And you are correct, I am creating the parent first but my validations are fine.  What is not fine is if someone clicks a link that takes them away from the form page for the child, which results in a parent object persisting, but no child

This will then increment the parent ID, but naturally, there is no child.parent_id being created (or ID for that matter)

Comment: I would create all at once using something like a wizard on the frontend if necessary to post all the params all at once. Don't create the parent until you have the child as well.

Comment: I notice that this is the same question likely as you posted yesterday 'Nested Forms: Deleting both objects if second form is left blank'? If so, I'd definitely use some sort of wizard library on the frontend with a nested form. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#configuring-the-model

Comment: Hey, thanks Isaiah, I will look into it.  Yeah, I posted it yesterday, and it got no hits... I figured I would try a more general approach to my question.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't exactly solve how to delete the parent, which actually, for functionality reasons, works out.

What was bugging me was the mismatch of ID's.

I solved that by simply assigning the parent.id to the new child.id at creation.

No more mismatch of IDS!  You had me go down a good rabbit hole, which resulted a solution.  Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Let active record validations do your job. Do you know you can do something like this:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teacher_students
  has_many :students, :through => :teacher_students
  validates :students, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
end
```

or if you don't want to validate this on create:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teacher_students
  has_many :students, :through => :teacher_students
  validates :students, :length => { :minimum => 1 }, on: :update
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately, in my case, this will prevent the parent from being created in the first place.  Any suggestions how to get around that?

Comment: try @teacher.save(validate: false) in create action. This will skip validations.

Comment: @TylerP3358 or you can try the alternate solution that I've provided in the updated answer

Comment: Thanks Abhilash, I will try it out here in a few!